# Can PHP analyze another web page?

Tags: php

I'm making a search engine that (in theory) analyzes online encyclopedias to get answers to a user's question from a form.  However, I want to know if I'm wasting my time with the PHP.  If I am, what language would be best suited to this task?  If I'm not, what function in PHP would allow me to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

PHP works as well as anything else. If you want to read data off of another webpage, you'll probably want to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), which is built in to PHP.

All of the requisite pieces are there: PHP does fine with processing text and HTML. If you already know PHP, it's best to stick with what you know.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough to do with PHP. If the sites you are getting the data from are valid xhtml it will be extremely easy to process the page and extract the data using the simplexml extension.